# Writing unicode json in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, character-encoding

In Ruby 2.0.0, I want to write an array to json:

```
require 'json'
File.open('test.json', 'w') do |f2| 
  f2.puts ["£2M worth of wine"].to_json  
end
```

This gives writes a file looking like this:

```
["┬ú2M worth of wine"]
```

Obviously, not what I am looking for. Is this a bug in `to_json`? How can I make it work?

Comment: what is your `os` ? and also the output of `puts json.encoding` ?

Comment: I am getting error in win7.. :-)

Comment: why not using Ruby stdlib - http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse ?

Comment: tell me the output of `puts "£2M worth of wine".encoding` ?

Comment: Could you try `File.open('test.json', 'wb', 'utf-8|ISO-8859-1') do |f2| .. end` ?

Comment: `£` in UTF-8 is the two bytes `C2 A3`. If you look at those bytes using [code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) they will appear as `┬ú`. So what you see is right, you just need to check the encoding of what you are using to view the file (possibly the console).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to force each element in the array to be encoded `UTF-8` before calling `to_json`

e.g:

```
["£2M worth of wine"].map { |str| str.encode("utf-8") }.to_json
```